# 'bits/c++config.h' not found when cross-compiling boost for android

Tags: android, c++, boost, cross-compiling

I'm getting this trivial error I can't figure out why, while cross-compiling boost 1.60 for Android.

I generated a toolchain for my architecture this way:

```
$NDK/build/tools/make_standalone_toolchain.py --arch arm64 --api 21 --unified-headers --install-dir ~/toolchain
```

Then, I created `user-config.jam` for boost:

```
toolchain = ~/toolchain

using clang : android : $(toolchain)/bin/aarch64-linux-android-clang++ : ;
```

Finally, this is how I'm trying to build boost:

```
./b2 -2 -j 4 --reconfigure target-os=android toolset=clang-android include=~/toolchain/include/c++/4.9.x link=static,shared variant=release threading=multi --prefix=`pwd`/build install
```

And I'm getting lots of errors, like:

```
~/toolchain/include/c++/4.9.x/iosfwd:38:10: fatal error: 'bits/c++config.h' file not found
#include <bits/c++config.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

I'm not quite sure why does toolchain not contain the above file